# SQL Server If Else Indexed View

Tags: sql-server, indexed-view

In SQL Server 2012, I would like to run a query that checks, if an indexed view exists. If it does, I want to run a `SELECT` statement `WITH(NOEXPAND)`. If it doesn't, I would like to run a select statement without expand. Below is the code I am using:

```
DECLARE @x int

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('test'))
    SET @x = 0
ELSE
    SET @x = 1

IF(@x = 1)
    SELECT category, _TimeStamp 
    FROM test WITH (NOEXPAND) 
    WHERE _TimeStamp >= '2018-01-24 00:00:00' 
      AND _TimeStamp < DATEADD(hh, +24, '2018-01-24 00:00:00') 
    ORDER BY _TimeStamp ASC

ELSE 
    SELECT category, _TimeStamp 
    FROM test
    WHERE _TimeStamp >= '2018-01-24 00:00:00' 
      AND _TimeStamp < DATEADD(hh, +24, '2018-01-24 00:00:00') 
    ORDER BY _TimeStamp ASC
```

As of running this query, there isn't an indexed view in the database for this table and I get following error:

> Msg 8171, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
>   Hint 'noexpand' on object 'test' is invalid.

I have another table that has an indexed view and if I run the same query on that table (with a little modifications such as table name), it runs just fine. I am wondering why does SQL Server complain about `NOEXPAND` when an indexed view does not exist, instead of running the statement in the Else part.

How else could I implement this?

---

EDIT: Changed the code to use exec() :

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('test'))

exec('SELECT category, _TimeStamp FROM test
WITH (NOEXPAND) Where _TimeStamp >= 2018-01-24 00:00:00 and _TimeStamp < DATEADD(hh, +24, 2018-01-24 00:00:00) ORDER BY _TimeStamp ASC')

Else 
SELECT cartegory, _TimeStamp FROM test
WHERE _TimeStamp >= '2018-01-24 00:00:00' and _TimeStamp < DATEADD(hh, +24, '2018-01-24 00:00:00') ORDER BY _TimeStamp ASC
```

_TimeStamp has datetime format.

Following error message received:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '00'.

Comment: Just a comment - for performance improvement change IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('test')) to IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('test')) - theres no need to select '*' where you are doing an exists check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query planner parses your entire query before it runs.  It will flag `noexpand` on the view as invalid, even though it's in a branch of an `if` clause that never gets executed.

You can solve this with `exec`, which runs in a separate scope:

```
IF(@x = 1)
    exec (N'SELECT category, _TimeStamp 
            FROM test WITH (NOEXPAND) 
            ...')
else
    SELECT category, _TimeStamp 
    FROM test
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped. A follow-up question - I now have SELECT category, _TimeStamp FROM test
WHERE _TimeStamp >= '2018-01-24 00:00:00' and _TimeStamp < DATEADD(hh, +24, '2018-01-24 00:00:00') ORDER BY _TimeStamp ASC     ... in the else part of my query. SQL complains about the time now. Incorrect syntax near '00'

Comment: Why not ask a new question instead of adding an unrelated question to an old question?  At any rate, the date in `exec` is missing quotes. You can add quotes to a string by repeating them, i.e. two single quotes, like in `''2018-01-24 00:00:00''`